# How to add a new line using sub and regex python?

Tags: python, regex

how can I add a new line (\n) between a "." and "[A-Z]" if there is no space or character between them? eg.

```
story = "Hello World. Hello World.Hello World.Hello World"

new_lines = findall('\.[A-Z]', story)
for new_line in new_lines:
    story = sub(new_line, '.\n[A-Z]', story)

print(story)
```

Output I'm trying to get is:

```
"Hello World. Hello World.\nHello World.\nHello World."
```

or

```
Hello World. Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World.
```

Comment: You are nearly there. Capture the uppercase in a group to be used in the replacement. Search for `\.([A-Z])` and replace with `\.\n\1`. Note, you'd want to use **raw-string** notation too.

Comment: Judging by your sample inputs and outputs. Are you also willing to add a `.` if there's none present at the end of a sentence? Or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex:

```regex
(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z])
```

- `(?<=\.)` positive lookbehind, find a `.`
- `(?=[A-Z])` positive lookahead, find a uppercased letter.

Using python:

```py
import re

story = "Hello World. Hello World.Hello World.Hello World."

story = re.sub(r'(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z])', '\n', story)

print(story)
```

Output:

```
Hello World. Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are looping the results of findall (re.findall) and then for item that findall returns, replace that with `.\n[A-Z]` setting that as the value of `story`

What you might do is match a dot, and assert a char A-Z to the right and just use `re.sub` and replace with a dot.

```
\.(?=[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GhL57j/1)

```
import re

regex = r"\.(?=[A-Z])"
story = "Hello World. Hello World.Hello World.Hello World"
story = re.sub(r"\.(?=[A-Z])", r".\n", story)
print (story)
```

Output

```
Hello World. Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World
```